# How to save Join Table with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm trying to create a simple app that lets the user save a driver, save a car and combine them (by a join table).

Driver model:

```
has_many :cars_drivers
has_many :cars, through: :cars_drivers
```

Car model:

```
has_many :cars_drivers
has_many :drivers, through: :cars_drivers
```

cars_driver model:

```
belongs_to :car, optional: true
belongs_to :driver, optional: true
```

I wanted to show all cars that the driver has been on so I added this on the drivers_controller:

```
def create
  @driver = Driver.new(driver_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @driver.save
      CarsDriver.where(driver_id: @driver.id).destroy_all
        form_cars_selected.each do |car_id|
          CarsDriver.create driver_id: @driver.id, car_id: car_id
        end
      format.html { redirect_to @driver, notice: 'Driver was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @driver }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @driver.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

and this is on the view:

```
<% if @driver.cars.blank? %>
  Driver has no cars.
<% else %>
  <%= @driver.cars.pluck(:description).to_sentence %>
<% end %>
```

But it doesn't work. What could I miss? Is there any easier way to set this basic relation in RoR?

Comment: Could you provide your ```show``` action template? And where the last code block is located?

Comment: @VasiliyNovikov yes, the show action is empty: def show  end.  and the last code block is located at show.html.erb

Comment: I think you faced that ```@driver``` variable not reloaded, so at the view it do not contain any cars. You can do it like ```@driver.cars << Car.where(id: form_cars_selected)``` and then again ```@driver.save```

Comment: Or ```@driver.update(car_ids: form_cars_selected)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `new/edit` `Driver` form you can add a [multi select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)

```
<%= form.select :car_ids, Car.order(:name).map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, {}, multiple: true %>
```

in the controller allow `car_ids: []` to `patient_params`

This way you can add cars to a Driver from Driver form

`_ids=` is a special [method](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many-collection-singular-ids-ids) that lets you create joins model

Comment: Now I got NameError in DriversController#create - undefined local variable or method `form_cars_selected' for #<DriversController:0x00007f8b0>

Comment: remove `CarsDriver.where(driver_id: @driver.id).destroy_all
        form_cars_selected.each do |car_id|
          CarsDriver.create driver_id: @driver.id, car_id: car_id
        end`

Comment: Thanks it's working. One thing, when I chose one car it does show it but when I edit to another car it shows the other one. How can I make it multiple cars? (I did that multiple: true you've mentioned). The menu lets me to choose only one at a time.

Comment: Update: It does let me choose multiple cars. I just had to press command while clicking on each car in the menu. Thanks